# git diff --word-diff gives wrong result

Tags: git, diff

Here are two text files to compare:

1.txt:

```
one three four five
```

2.txt:

```
one two three four
```

Here are commands to create diff (for Windows):

```
git init
copy 1.txt temp
git add temp
copy 2.txt temp
git diff --minimal --word-diff
del temp
xrmdir /s /q ".git"
```

Here is the output:

```
diff --git a/temp b/temp
index 555f964..d993b66 100644
--- a/temp
+++ b/temp
@@ -1 +1 @@
one {+two+} three four[-five-]
```

If we want to see original 1.txt by looking at diff, we'd see

```
one  three fourfive
```

(double space between one and three, no space between four and five).

Is there a way (command, I presume) to fix this, or is this normal? Am I missing something?

P.S.: git --version == 1.8.3.mysysgit.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the git-diff manpage:

> plain
>
> Show words as [-removed-] and {+added+}. Makes no attempts to escape the delimiters if they appear in the input, so the output may
>   be ambiguous.
>
> porcelain
>
> Use a special line-based format intended for script consumption. Added/removed/unchanged runs are printed in the usual unified diff
>   format, starting with a +/-/ character at the beginning of the line
>   and extending to the end of the line. Newlines in the input are
>   represented by a tilde ~ on a line of its own.

The result you get is working as expected. **Makes no attempts to escape the delimiters if they appear in the input, so the output may be ambiguous.**

So when I run `git diff --minimal --word-diff=porcelain` I get the response:

```
diff --git a/home/me/temp b/home/me/temp
index 29338da..4d0e08d 100644
--- a/home/me/temp
+++ b/home/me/temp
@@ -1 +1 @@
 one 
+two
  three four
-five
~
```

which keeps the whitespace.